# Python 3.4 - Formatting String Input into Title format

Tags: python, python-3.4

I'm a bit of a python amateur and I'm creating an extremely basic program. I need it to format a user's input into title format like so:

*Input: hello*

*Output: Hello*

This is what I have so far:

`firstNameInput = input("Hello! What is your first name? \n")`

`firstName = firstNameInput.title`

When I come to print firstName I get no error, however instead of printing firstName it prints:

`<built-in method title of str object at 0x0000000003EA60D8>`

Thanks for any help in advance! :)

Comment: `firstNameInput.title()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`firstNameInput.title()` you are missing parens

```
In [1]: s = "hello world"

In [2]:print (s.title)
Out[2]:<built-in method title of str object at 0x7fbea30830b0>

In [3]: s.title()
Out[3]: 'Hello World'
```

The first is a reference to the method, the second is actually calling it.

Comment: Thanks very much! Works fine, silly mistake, probably shouldn't attempt to do this while tired :)

Comment: No worries, it happens to most people at some stage!