# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, attributeerror

Tried to run this code, but error says that I have made a mistake with .title . How can I fix this? (Please note that I am still an amateur in the world of Python, and am open to any suggestions which could improve my code. However, chances are that I will not understand it unless it is explained, if it is something new e.g. you could use __________ instead of _________ .)

Here's my code:

```
import time
import sys

print("Welcome to my quiz")
time.sleep(2)
input('Press enter to continue')

score = int(0)
failed = int(0)

def points():
    print("Correct! Well done!")
    global score
    score = score + 1

def fail():
    print("Oh no, that is incorrect")
    global failed
    failed = failed + 1

def printtotal():
    global score
    global failed
    print("You have ",score,"points, and ",failed,"/3 lives used.")

if failed == 5:
    sys.exit('Program terminated.')

print('You will have 5 seconds to answer each question \nIf you fail 5 times or more, the program will exit')
time.sleep(3)
print('Good luck!')
time.sleep(2)

q1 = print(input("What is the capital of England?")).title
if q1 == 'London':
    points()
else:
    fail()
printtotal()

q2 = print(input("Who is the prime minister's wife?")).title
if q2 == 'Samantha' or 'Samantha Cameron':
    points()
else: 
   fail()
printtotal()

print('How would you say \'I came, I saw, I conquered\' in latin?')
print('a) veni, vidi, vici')
print('b) veni, vedi, vici')
print('c) vini, vedi, vici')
q3 = print(input('Type the letter here:'))
if q3 == 'a)' or 'a':
    points()
else:
    fail()
printtotal()
```

If I try to execute this code, this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Desktop/Python_Stuff/quiz.py", line 34, in <module>
    q1 = print(input("What is the capital of England?")).title
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'title'
```

If anyone happens to spot anymore errors, please do tell me. How can I fix this error?

Comment: You need to move the second close parenthesis to the end of the line.  You also should do `.title()`, not `.title`.

Comment: I saw like 4 python questions with typos in the past hour, I feel like there is a python assignment due tomorrow at some university.

Answer (score 1):

The `print` function does not return anything, or more specifically it returns `NoneType`. Thus, you can't get the value of it's member `title`.

```
print(input("What is the capital of England?")).title
```

Is equivalent to:

```
answer = input("What is the capital of England?")
print(answer).title
```

But `print(answer)` will simply print out whatever the user inputted *and then return a None object*. What you actually want is:

```
print(input("What is the capital of England?").title())
```

[See this for more about print and title.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717603/python-3-4-formatting-string-input-into-title-format)

This will uncover a separate problem with your code: that you're trying to simultaneously input something and print the question for which you want input. In which case [this is what you want](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html):

```
q1 = input("What is the capital of England?")  # This will automatically print 'What is...' when it reaches this point in the program
```

The above will save the user input to `q1`.

Comment: What he actually wants is to store the input in the variables `q1`, `q2` etc., so printing outright is also wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the problem is with this line:

```
q1 = print(input("What is the capital of England?")).title
```

What you're doing here is asking for user input (with the `input` function of python3.x), and then printing that result to standard out (usually, that is the screen or "the terminal window"). However, `print` does not return anything special, so in python terminology, it returns `None`. `None` is a singleton (consider it a special type of variable) that does not have the attribute `title`, so you can't type e.g. `None.title`.

Consider just storing the input to `q1`, like this:

```
q1 = input("What is the capital of England?")
```

Answer (score 0):

`print()` returns `None`. Therefore, `print(...).title` raises the `AttributeError` that you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

`print` doesn't have a attribute called "title". That is, you can't do:

```
print().title
```

Really I think what you want to do is get rid of `print()` entirely, so like this:

```
q1 = input("What is the capital of England?")
if q1 == 'London':
```